# Undo Redo pattern for high performance? C#

Tags: c#, performance

I am looking for a undo redo system that allows me to log changes of properties.
After searching a bit I found the memento pattern. 
I took the idea and wrote it in my classes:

Basic Structure:

```
public class Face 
{
    List<Vertex> vertices;
}

public class Vertex : ValueLog<Vertex>
{
    Vector3 _position;
    public Vector3 Position
    {
        set { Log(); _position = value; }
        get { return _position; }
    }

    public Vertex(Vector3 position)
    {
        _position = position;
    }

    protected override void Restore(Vertex value)
    {
        _position = value._position;
    }

    protected override Vertex GetLogValue()
    {
        return new Vertex(_position);
    }
}
```

ValueLog class to keep track of the modification history:

```
public abstract class ValueLog<T> : ICmd
{
    Stack<T> undoStack;
    Stack<T> redoStack;

    bool logged = false;

    public ValueLog()
    {
        undoStack = new Stack<T>();
        redoStack = new Stack<T>();
    }

    protected abstract void Restore(T value);
    protected abstract T GetLogValue();

    protected void Log()
    {
        if (!logged && !Logger.Instance.logPaused)
        {
            logged = true;

            redoStack.Clear();
            undoStack.Push(GetLogValue());

            // add log operation to a list of operations that happen at once 
            Logger.Instance.AddCmd(this); 

            Logger.Instance.OnCollect += OnCollect;
        }
    }

    public override void Undo()
    {
        if (undoStack.Count > 0)
        {
            T current = GetLogValue();
            redoStack.Push(current);

            T restore = undoStack.Pop();
            Restore(restore);
        }
    }

    public override void Redo()
    {
        if (redoStack.Count > 0)
        {
            T current = GetLogValue();
            undoStack.Push(current);

            T restore = redoStack.Pop();
            Restore(restore);
        }
    }

    void OnCollect()
    {
        // called when operation finished (On Mouse Up)
        logged = false;
        Logger.Instance.OnCollect -= OnCollect;
    }
}
```

So far it works fine. However I plan to have about a million of vertices. If I set the position of 100.000 of them at the same time I expect some performance problems. Also storage will be critical if each Vertex stores two Stacks.

- Is there something I can optimize?
- Is there a better pattern to solve this?
- Is it possible to move this on a gpu to run faster?

Thank you for reading and answers! Sorry for this code heavy question. This is only the important part of the code. I don't want to explode the question with the whole code.

Comment: Can you also show us the implementation of `Logger` and the definition of `ICmd`?

Comment: This is not a code-heave question, in fact, there is a lot of code missing. Could you add all parts please?